# Cannot get Firebase working for Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, developing an App using Xamarin Forms, for Android and iOS. Everything is the latest version.

I am trying to use Firebase to add Push Notification functionality. I have been able to get this functioning for the Android App, but whatever I do seems to fail / not work for iOS.

I have tried using both Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging and Plugin.FirebasePushNotification with the same result. Starting from a basic app created in Visual Studio, as soon as I add the basic code for the iOS project, the app stops working and just times out after 17 seconds with running any of the project code (no breakpoints are hit).

I also tried downloading this demo app https://github.com/jfversluis/XFFCMPushNotificationsSample. I created my versions of google-services.json (Android) and GoogleService-Info.plist (iOS). The Android app runs but the iOS app does not (times out after 17 seconds).

Having tried so many different samples, examples, options, etc - I am at a complete loss as to what the issue might be. The situation is not helped by me being new to App development & Xamarin Forms!

I appreciate that I haven't added any "I tried this" code, but I'm hoping someone can help me with debugging this. Visual Studio doesn't appear to show anything, can I get more helpful info from the iPhone?

Edit:

For iOS,

- I have created a Key and enabled Apple Push Notifications.
- I have uploaded the key to the iOS project in Firebase (Cloud Messaging).
- I have downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file and added it to the iOS project in Visual Studio, and set it to BundleResource
- I have enabled Push Notifications in Entitlements.plist
- I have enabled Background Modes & Remote Notifications in Info.plist
- I am using Automatic Provisioning
- I have checked that Bundle Identifier is correct
- I have added FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to info.plist

EDIT 2:
I have manged to get an error message, which happens during the call to

FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);

{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Plugin.FirebasePushNotification.FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize (Foundation.NSDictionary options, System.Boolean autoRegistration) [0x00029] in /Users/runner/runners/2.169.1/work/1/s/Plugin.FirebasePushNotification/FirebasePushNotificationManager.ios.cs:141
at MyApp.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00014] in \MyKRing.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:34 }

Comment: getting push notifications working involves a lot more than just downloading a sample app and running it.  There is a lot of platform configuration that needs to be done on the Apple/Google side.  From your post its not clear that you've done any of this.

Comment: Apologies - the Android side of things works OK. for iOS, I have configured the provisioning, as far as I can tell. Again, I have followed a number of different tutorials for that part. Of course, there is a chance I've done something wrong, but it "seems" to work?

Comment: Any luck? I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: @NickDichiaro sorry, I can't remember the specific solution, but I was possibly when I had a remote virtual Mac and was running the iOS version via the simulator (on Windows). I now have a physical Mac for iOS testing (with an iPhone connected via USB).